# Automate Microsoft Project 2010 launch

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

I am looking for some way for automate Microsoft Project 2010 launching when exported file is created by another project management software.

Is it possible to force MSP2010 to open the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do a little scripting, this sounds like a perfert job for an [AutoIt Script](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).  You could have the script look for the exported file every few seconds and then, once seen, have AutoIt open the file in MSP2010.  Their forums are also very helpful.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is interesting. But is there also a possibility to launch it via PHP or ASP.NET, for instance?